# I am trying to fetch json data's from .php file.php file i.e stored in server.I have writtened the following code.But I am unable to fetch data

Tags: php, html, json, parsing, cordova

I am new to this jquery and phonegap.I am finding little difficulty in parsing the data from .php file from a local server.Please help me in doing so.

This is my index.html page:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <h2>JSON Parser</h2>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"/></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function parseJSON()
           {

               var json;
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://192.168.1.12/training/services/login.php',
                    cache: false,
                    // data: $('#abc').serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                            $('#data').append(data);
                       }
                    });


              }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="parseJSON()">
    <p>Employee's Information</p>
    <form id="abc" method ="post">
    <div id="data"></div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The login.php file contains a sample json data's as follows:

```
{"username":"test@test.com","password":"password"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand correctly you may do something like that.
If your php page send data to your html one, you may use GET instead of POST

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<h2>JSON Parser</h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parse()
       {
           var json;
           $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://192.168.1.12/training/services/login.php',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                   {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        $('#data').html(obj["username"]);
                   }
                });
          }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="parse()">
<p>Employee's Information</p>
<form id="abc" method ="post">
<div id="data"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the above code but it was not displaying any values in Emulator.I made some changes as follows:$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
               url:'http://192.168.1.12/training/services/login.php',        
                success: function(data)
                   {
              
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        $('#data').html(obj["username"]);
                   }
                });   It is giving the exact output

Comment: Yes..Its Working we have to make some changes has I mentioned above in comments.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the data using php and ajax use jsonp,

in your PHP file add callback for json output:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($data).')';exit;
```

apppend callback in your ajax call

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.1.12/training/services/login.php?callback=?',              
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And last but not least, dont forget to add domain white list for your localhost

in corodova.xml:

```
<access origin="http://192.168.1.12"/> OR
<access origin="*"/> to allow all domains
```